# Service not being mocked when testing with Aurelia

Tags: phantomjs, aurelia, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a couple of services in an Aurelia test, but one is getting the mock injected, the other is getting the real service injected. I can't see what the difference is.

I have a couple of service mocks in my test spec:

```
export class MockCommunicationService {
    imAmock = true;
    get(id: number): Promise<ICommunication> {
        return Promise.resolve({} as ICommunication);
    }
}

export class MockRoundService {
    getRounds(): Promise<IRoundList[]> {
        return Promise.resolve([{} as IRoundList]);
    }
}
```

You can see the `imAmock` test property I put in there to check later on.

My test (in TypeScript) looks something like this, taken mostly from the aurelia hub docs on testing:

```
describe('Communications', () => {
    let component: ComponentTester;
    let container: Container;
    let viewModel: Communications; // <-- the real type
    let service = new MockCommunicationService();
    let roundService = new MockRoundService();

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = new Container();
        viewModel = container.get(Communications);
        component = StageComponent
            .withResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('path/to/real/communications'))
            .inView('<communications></communications>')
            .boundTo(viewModel);

        component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
            aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
                .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"));

            aurelia.container.registerInstance(RoundService, roundService);
            aurelia.container.registerInstance(CommunicationService, service);
        });
    });

    it('should be mocked', done => {
        component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
            expect(viewModel.communicationService.imAmock).toBe(true);
            done();
        }).catch(e => { console.log(e.toString()) });
    });
});
```

This fails with imAmock being undefined. If I `console.log(viewModel.communicationService)` I can see the real communication service with all it's injected dependencies (such as http, etc.)

But, if I do exactly the same for `RoundService`, the mock above is injected as you would expect.

the viewModel itself uses `@autoinject` the same way for both services:

```
@autoinject()
export class Communications {
    ...
    constructor(public readonly communicationService: CommunicationService, public readonly roundService: RoundService,
        private readonly bindingEngine: BindingEngine, private readonly eventAggregator: EventAggregator, private readonly animator: CssAnimator,
        private readonly validationControllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory) {
        ...
    }
}
```

(I made those first two public so I could get access to them in the test, but they're normally private)

The only hint I can find is that the Aurelia DI implementation uses a map of keys (usually the class) to resolve instances. If I've somehow defined the `CommunicationService` twice then I may be getting two different keys for the same class... But I can't see how that would happen or how to fix it.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT!
Thanks to [@adam-willden below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484075/1089267), I started thinking how I could reorder the registration and first container.get call, and I came up with this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    container = new Container();

    component = StageComponent
        .withResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('path/to/real/communications'))
        .inView('<communications></communications>')
        .boundTo(viewModel);

    component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
        aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
            .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"));

        aurelia.container.registerInstance(RoundService, roundService);
        aurelia.container.registerInstance(CommunicationService, service);

        viewModel = aurelia.container.get(Communications);    
    });
});
```

It works a treat, and both services are now mocks.

---

EDIT2
I'm not sure what I tried earlier but my code above doesn't work! So I'm back to square one - how do I inject a service into a test?

Answer (score 1):

Having just looked it over, it appears to me that you're requesting the Communications instance from the container before you've registered the Mock instances.

I've not quite got the time to test for the correct solution (if you'd provided a gist Id have modified that for you). But given you're already using a container to get your viewmodel, can you not move these lines above the `container.get` to make:

```
container.registerInstance(RoundService, roundService);
container.registerInstance(CommunicationService, service);
viewModel = container.get(Communications);
component = StageComponent
        .withResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('path/to/real/communications'))
        .inView('<communications></communications>')
        .boundTo(viewModel);

component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
    aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"));
});
```

Comment: not quite, in fact that stopped my simple `expect(true).toBe(true);` test from working. However, you got me onto the right track of trying to reorder the registration after the container.get, and I came up with my edit to my question (give me a sec to write it). Since you pointed me there, happy to mark this as accepted if you update your answer.

Comment: [As I mentioned in gitter](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss?at=59ceb446cfeed2eb6568840f) I don't get how your solution works and so I don't want to update my answer to something I don't understand. I'm not sure why my solution didn't work either.